# Uncaught TypeError: CalEvents.insert is not a function

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I`m learning meteor from video lessons. I can not add events to calendar, it gives an error in console: Uncaught TypeError: CalEvents.insert is not a function
[image: error]
This is my .js file:

```
CalEvents = new Meteor.Collection('calevents');
Session.setDefault('editing_calevents', null);
Session.setDefault('showEditEvent', false);
Session.setDefault('lastMod', null)

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('homepage');
});

Router.route('/calendar', function () {
  this.render('calendar');
});

Template.calendar.showEditEvent = function(){
    return Session.get('showEditEvent');
}
Template.calendar.rendered = function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        dayClick:function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
            CalEvents.insert({title:'New Event', start:date,end:date});
            Session.set('lastMod', new Date());
        },
        eventClick:function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
            Session.set('editing_calevents', calEvent.id);
            Session.set('showEditEvent', true);
        },
        events:function(start, end, callback){
           var events = [];
            CalEvents = CalEvents.find();
            CalEvents.forEach(function(evt){
                events.push({
                    id:evt._id,
                    title:evt.title,
                    start:evt.start,
                    end:evt.end
                })
            })
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}

Template.calendar.lastMod = function(){
    return Session.get('lastMod');
}
```

This is calendar.html file:

```
    <template name="calendar">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div id="calendar">
         {{#if showEditEvent}}
         {{>editEvent}}
         {{/if}}
         <input type="hidden" name="lastMod" id="lastMod"  value="{{lastMod}}">

         </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
</template>
<template name='editEvent'>
    <div id="example" class="modal">
    <div class="modle-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Body</h4>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="model-footer">
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Save</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cansel</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

There were questions similar like this, but not exactly the same. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Answer below is fine, you should read more about meteor:
http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html

Answer (score 1):

`CalEvents` is initially set to a `Meteor.Collection` instance. Change this to:

```
CalEvents = new Mongo.Collection('calevents');
```

Later in your code, you are reassigning it to a cursor:

```
CalEvents = CalEvents.find();
```

When `dayClick` runs, it finds that `CalEvents` is a cursor so it doesn't have an `insert` function.

The solution is just to choose another variable name in the `events` callback:

```
var CalEventsCursor = CalEvents.find();
CalEventsCursor.forEach(...)
```

Also, `rendered` was replaced with the [onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) a while back.

Comment: I have done everything like you said, but now it says insert failed: Method not found :-(

Comment: I updated the answer with another change. The tutorial you are following seems pretty out of date. Anyway, you are probably just writing over the variable somewhere else. If you can make a public repository of the code, I'd be happy to look at it.